# Mapped Network Share to Media folder

Tags: networking, usb, mount, permissions, samba

I am really new to linux and i have two ubuntu machines at home each with a usb hard drive plugged in.

I managed to share the drives between the two machines so they both have read and write permissions.

Today i was trying to permanently mount the drive plugged into machine 2 on machine 1.

I succeeded however i have managed to map it to the "media" folder (/media) so now my real media which is plugged in has dropped off. I understand now that i was supposed to map this somewhere else but i don't know how to unmap it and get my media folder back ?

To mount the drive i used

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.36/Media -o username=olly /Media
```

My  Fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=78734aad-4572-4659-a607-432f668b8549 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2586ab21-15aa-4a5d-9590-cabeae9c3dd5 none            swap    sw              0       0

//192.168.0.36/Media mnt/Media cifs credentials=/home/olly/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Sorry if this is very vague i am very new to linux

Thanks in advance!

Olly

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain what you did to permanently mount the drive, and then post the contents of the file `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

1. remove or comment the modification in fstab

> **#** //192.168.0.36/Media mnt/Media cifs credentials=/home/olly/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

2. unmount the current remote location

> sudo umount //192.168.0.36/Media

3. create a new location where to mount

> sudo mkdir /mnt/MyShare

4. edit fstab t mount to the new location (I would also recommend using _netdev)

> //192.168.0.36/Media mnt/MyShare cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/olly/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

5. reboot